# Sampling Sequences in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a bunch sequential data, and I want to sample, with replacement, random **sequences** of items (e.g. 50 days at a time).

If I do something like `df.sample(50,replace=True)`, it just pulls 50 random rows out of a hat.

I've written code that does the trick, but it's not nice. Is there a standard way to do this in pandas?

Comment: `I've written code that does the trick, but it's not nice.` - you may want to show us a simplified - not so nice implementation of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Python2.7, index your dataframe on dates, sort and then you can select rows very nicely like so:

```
my_df.iloc(xrange(10, 60))
```

Obviously ensure the 2nd argument to `xrange < my_df.shape[0]`. It's easy to randomise the selected range.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.where((df.date >= 1/1/16) & (df.date <= 3/15/16)) , 50, replace=True)]
```